# Spring boot Timezone in http request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to take Timezone from http request with spring boot?
In mapping part, Timezone object is set to server Timezone

Comment: How are you sending the values? Are you mapping them to ZonedDateTime or some other type that supports timezones? Can you put your example and the code in the question.

Comment: @GetMapping({"/"}) get(@RequestParam....  , Timezone timezone) { timezone.getID()}.       They suggest that is the http request timezone but with changed Timezone on computer, I get timezone that is on server

Answer (score 0):

Examine the `@SessionAttribute`s:

```java
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(Model model, Locale locale, TimeZone zone,
                    @SessionAttribute Optional<String> languageTag,
                    @SessionAttribute Optional<String> zoneID) {
        if (languageTag.isPresent()) {
            locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag.get());
        }

        if (zoneID.isPresent()) {
            zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneID.get());
        }

        model.addAttribute("locale", locale);
        model.addAttribute("zone", zone);
...
```